# Required Blob is missing when preview data of a copy data activity sink dataset

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline, parquet, copy-data

I am new to Azure. I created a new ADF, pipeline, storage blob account and a copy data activity, the source is from a SQL server table and the sink output is a parquet file. But when I preview the data of my sink dataset, I got an error saying the required blob is missing.

I want to create a directory as well but weather I type in the folder name and file name or using parameters, I still receive the error. If I manually upload a file via the Azure Storage Explorer, the preview will have no issue.

Anyone what I missed?

Thanks for the help.

cheers
Albert

Answer (score 1):

I created linked service for Azure SQL database and blob storage account and created dataset of SQL database for source:

[image]

Dataset of blob storage for sink:

[image]

When I preview the data by entering file name I got below error:

[image]

I got above error because I am not having that file in my blob storage.
In data factory the file will create automatically while debug the pipeline without entering filename.
I just gave the file path where my parquet file need save in sink dataset and debug the pipeline, it executed successfully.

[image]

My SQL table is copied to blob storage as parquet file successfully.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't realize the first time need to use debug to create the path and file and using "review data" will not work.